New run blocks final job in preceeding run until queue is equal to agent pool size
We've been having an issue over the past few months where an in-progress Azure Pipelines run/build will end up with a single job stuck at queue priority 1 if a new run begins before it manages to work down the existing queued jobs. The job does eventually start and complete, but only once there are no other jobs in the queue for newer runs.

The job that gets blocked isn't consistent - can be different every time it occurs.
Most noticeable in a particular .yaml pipeline that contains about 17 jobs of varying durations that can run in any order. This will regularly queue back to back for different pull requests.
The same job in the subsequent run can complete before the original one starts.
The job that's blocked remains at queue priority 1, but realistically behaves like it's at the end of the queue - all other jobs queued are 2 onwards and seem to take precedence.
We have four self-hosted (VM) agents available to this pipeline. Our included/purchased entitlements cover five self-hosted agents in total as we have other agents that can run unrelated pipelines.

Some screenshots of the run/queue states the last time it occurred below.
Run queue:
Run queue
Original run with blocked job at priority 1:
Original, blocked run
Newer run with no blocked jobs, all either running or starting from priority 2:
New, not blocked run
The blocked job showing the priority:
Priority 1 blocked job in question
I've had a bit of a search for the issue in particular, as well as a browse through recent pipeline/job related issues here, which didn't turn up much.
I've reviewed the range of jobs in the .yaml pipeline and we don't use any particular means to control the flow of the jobs - they should run in any order.
Since it's a newish issue and my searches didn't turn up much I thought I'd start here before considering whether a support plan is justified. Thanks!
Update
I'm going to try describe the scenario we see below, simplified somewhat:

3 self-hosted agents (3 entitlements).
A single .yaml-defined pipeline containing 4 jobs, no stages and no dependencies.
We will run this pipeline twice, the second immediately after the first is scheduled.


Pipeline run 1 starts, immediately kicking off 3 of the 4 jobs. Job 4 is put into queue position 1.
Pipeline run 2 starts, queuing 4 of the 4 jobs.
We now have 3 running jobs and 5 queued jobs with a priority of 1 through 5, the first being the final job from our first run.
The first of the three active jobs completes.
Rather than the job with queue priority 1 starting, the job with queue priority 2 starts instead. 3 through to 5 shuffle up to become 2 through to 4. Job with priority 1 is still sitting inactive at priority 1.
A second job completes, and the above happens again - job with priority 1 is passed over.

Because the 4th job from the first run was set to queue priority 1, I would expect it to immediately start once one of the first active jobs completes. Rather, it doesn't seem to start until it is the last item in the queue.
I'm not sure if the issue can be reproduced reliably, or if there's some unknown factor at play.

Update
You haven't clarified how the behavior is reproduced, but as far as I can imagine, there are scenarios to reproduce this behavior, that an agent job won't take a position in the queue until the dependent jobs complete and resource checks are passed.
For example, there is a PipelineA that has two stages, stage1 with job1 and stage2 with job2. You have configured checks for the resources (dependencies, service connections, environments, variable groups, agent pools etc.) used by stage2.
When you run PipelineA, job1 of stage1 may be running first; however, because the dependent job1 is not completed or the resource checks are not passed, job2 of stage2 will NOT take any position in the queue; it is in pending state not queued state.

At this moment, if many other agent jobs with no dependencies or checks are coming in, they will directly take the positions of the queue in front of job2; thus, they are in queued state, while job2 may still be pending.
When job2 is finally in queued state, it will then have to wait for the previous queued jobs to complete first.
I can understand your requirement to complete all the agent jobs of a pipeline that is triggered before others. However, with the example above, we can easily discover it will be a waste of time to assign a front position for a pending job and have all the other queued jobs in rear positions wait together with this job, which will result in the increase in the overall time of agent jobs.
With those being said, to reduce the overall agent job time, consider purchasing more parallel jobs.

Based on your description, it seemed that you only setup several self-hosted agents but didn't purchase any self-hosted parallel jobs.

Please be noted that if your organization only has the single free self-hosted parallel job, there will be only one agent job running at a time to consume or say, occupy a self-hosted parallel job, then pick up only one single self-hosted agent and run the steps defined under this job, no matter how many agents you have added into your self-hosted agent pool(s); thus all the other jobs defined in the same pipeline or the jobs from other pipelines will be stuck in the queue to wait for the previous agent job to complete and the self-hosted parallel job is released.
If you would run multiple self-hosted agent jobs of in parallel to reduce the time pending in the queue, you can, on one hand, buy as many additional self-hosted parallel jobs as you actually need, and on the other hand, to define your pipeline to run agent jobs in the Microsoft-hosted agent pool of Azure Pipelines to leverage the single free Microsoft-hosted parallel job. Please also note that all your MS-hosted or self-hosted parallel jobs are consumed by all the agent pools shared in all projects. In another word, for example, if the single free self-hosted parallel job is occupied by one of the jobs from the pipelines in project A, the other agent job(s) defined in the same pipeline or other pipelines from project A or other projects will all have to wait in the queue.
Per the other query in this post to control the sequence of the jobs from a pipeline/stage, we can add dependencies; otherwise, those jobs will run in parallel in any order.

Sorry, I should have clarified (and will update the question)
We have four dedicated self-hosted agents that can run these jobs. We have five self-hosted agent entitlements (three purchased, one included and one as part of another subscription).
This isn't a new pipeline. It's a new issue in an existing pipeline.
As for the dependencies, I have considered adding 'fake' dependencies to attempt to control the order, but it's not really the same thing. They don't depend on one another, although we would like to guarantee the longer jobs start first. It's not a high priority.

Appreciate your update. Can you please specify your requirements to control this problematic pipeline? Would you share a minimal YAML pipeline sample to help elaborate on your expectations? May I assume you would like to control the jobs sequence for this single pipeline? If that is the case, the job dependencies properties should work for you. If possible, please let us know what your concerns are when trying such suggestions. Thx again for the sharing.

To clarify again, the sequence/order isn't the concern. The issue is that one job/task within the first pipeline run gets blocked by an entirely new pipeline run that's scheduled afterwards, despite the blocked job remaining in queue position 1 the entire time, and won't start until the new run completes. I should have left out any mention of controlling the job order.

A pipeline being queued first doesn't mean all the jobs in it will run prior to any other job queued afterward.

So, your concern is why your so-called Priority 1 agent job from a pipeline run that was triggered before the jobs in other pipeline runs would keep waiting? You would expect your ran a pipeline first, so all the jobs in this pipeline run should take a position in the queue in front of any other agent jobs from the pipeline runs triggered afterwards?

Please check the updated answer to explain the job queueing behavior. Hope it helps resolve your concern in this post.

Appreciate the detail you've put in to the answer, but unfortunately the pipeline contains 17 independent jobs on equal footing that can run in any order - we haven't used any stages. I would  therefore expect all 17 jobs to be assigned a position in the queue on starting that run, and any subsequent runs to be assigned job positions following the previous ones. This is what happens.
The issue is that the job with 'position in queue 1' is stuck, and jobs in positions 2 through to n run first - equivalent jobs that, according to their queue position, should not take priority.

Thanks for the update to help rule out the scenario. That is indeed weird. I am not sure if there are other possibilities to incur this behavior given phased findings.  Would you consider creating a support ticket and engage further investigation by a one one support engineer, as it may be insecure to share further troubleshooting information in public community?
